# iOS component for implementing an in-app tutorial

Tags: gratis, software-development, ios

I am the author of an existing iOS app. I would like to improve the app by adding an in-app tutorial. Instead of implementing everything from scratch, I was thinking that there might be a software component or framework out there that I could reuse, but so far I have been unable to find anything.

Requirements:

- Must be free (as in free beer)
- Should be open source
- Can be integrated into a plain Objective-C project that uses UIKit to implement the UI
- Must support both iPhone and iPad
- Must support iOS 7 and later

About the most basic tutorial that I can think of is a series of popups that point out user interface elements (e.g. toolbar buttons) and display information about them. A more advanced tutorial would be able to set a goal that the user must achieve to get to the next step of the tutorial. These are just some of my ideas, but actually I am quite willing to get inspired by the capabilities of whatever recommendations you can pull out of your hat.